# no network connection with ubuntu-sdk

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, meizu-mx4

I try to connect my phone (Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition) to ubuntu sdk. The phone connects to ubuntu sdk, but when i go to the 'Devices' tab, this message appears:

> No network connection on your device!
>   You will need to connect your device to a network with connection to the Internet.
>   Then replug the device to your workstation.

It doesn't matter whether the screen is unlocked or not. Tried 4G and WIFI. Developer mode is on.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem..
If you have just like me added SDK to a existing QT installation.
It is maybe necessary to add next repository!

1) Close QT

2) Open terminal and enter "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa"

3) Update your system

4) Read for example http://itsfoss.com/install-configure-ubuntu-sdk/

5) Open QT or Ubuntu SDK (i don't see any difference between them)

6) creat a kit armhf-ubuntu-sdk-15.04 or armhf-ubuntu-sdk-14.10, depending on your phone

I created a new project (simpleui) and can run it on my phone.

Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition using armhf-ubuntu-sdk-15.04 kit